# Calling hjkl keys from vim's command line

Tags: vim, fold

Whenever I am browsing folded code in vim and press the `l` key I want it to open that fold recursively. For that I did the following: `nmap l lzO`. Which worked ok, apart from the fact of getting a `E490: No fold found` whenever I would press `l` not in a fold. I used that an excuse to learn about Vimscript and write a function for that and avoid the error.

Now, I am missing the part of **how can I call a vim command like `l` or `lzO` from inside a function?**

```
function! OpenFoldOrNot()
    if foldclosed(line(".")) == -1
        echo "just l"
        l # TODO
    else
        echo "open fold"
        lzO # TODO
    endif
endfunction

nmap l :call OpenFoldOrNot()<CR>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `normal` command. For this case you will need `normal!` to avoid recursive execution of your function.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following, using the [normal](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/29.html) command (my vimscript is very rusty):

```
function! OpenFoldOrNot()
    if foldclosed(line(".")) == -1
        normal! l
    else
        normal! lzO
    endif
endfunction

nmap l :call OpenFoldOrNot()<CR>
```

Comment: There is no need for `execute`, unless you intend to use the printable format of some special character such as `<CR>` or `<ESC>`.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. As I said, my vimscript is very rusty ;)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use a map-expression to make this kind of job easier.

```
nnoremap <expr> l foldclosed(line(".")) == -1 ? 'l' : 'lzO'
```

In a map expression the right hand side, `{rhs}`, of the mapping is a VimScript expression. This is evaluated to obtain what to execute. In your case it is used to determine if the mapping calls `l` or `lz0`.

For more help see:

```
:h :map-expression
```